# Using MSDeploy to migrate a large SQL Server Compact database to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-ce, webdeploy

I've been trying to use the API provided by Web Deploy to transfer a SQL Server Compact database to a SQL Server database. This seems to work fine, until I try to use a SQL Server CE database file larger than the default size limit (256MB), in which case I get one of two errors.

If I don't specify the max database size in my connection string:

> The database file is larger than the configured maximum database size. This setting takes effect on the first concurrent database connection only. [ Required Max Database Size (in MB; 0 if unknown) = 0 ]

If I define it, I get:

> Keyword not supported: 'max database size'.

This seems like a straight up bug with Web Deploy, but I thought I could get around it by creating a connection first to "initialize" the max database size, as [this blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlservercompact/2007/06/13/the-story-of-max-database-size-connection-string-parameter/) hints at, to no avail.

Did I miss some angle? Is there any way I can use the Web Deploy to get this to work correctly? Or should I give up and use a different tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my free SQL Server Compact Toolbox, it allows you to migrate to SQL Server both via scripts and via a one click GUI option. It is available as a standalone desktop app, Visual Studio extension and SSMS extension, and a number of command line tools.

Comment: I'm actually looking at replacing MSDeploy's API for ExportSQLCE but have been hitting similar sizing issues in my initial tests. With large sets of data it isn't possible to use the API (in Generator4) directly as I get out of memory exceptions as the '//split large output' block doesn't get called.

Comment: That SHOULD work, if not, it is a bug I will fix, please post an issue on github with your code to call the API and I will look into it!